# Exibição incorreta de caracteres em página html/jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

Estava projetando um site para fins acadêmicos, mas me deparei com um erro de visualização. Minhas páginas html/jsp não estão exibindo os textos acentuados corretamente ao recuperar do banco de dados.
Todas estão com charset UTF-8 na tag meta e lang pt-br na tag html. O banco que uso é o MySQL 5.7. Tanto para inserir como para exibir no shell do mysql, os acentos são exibidos corretamente. O problema ocorre quando insiro ou edito um registro via página html/jsp, aí, seja exibindo na página ou no shell, os caracteres ficam bugados.

Exemplo de uma linha:

> Alessandro sÃ£o raimundo   Sem email       000012341234    17/07/1990

Dentro de um form de um .jsp, eu altero um contato mandando os parâmetros para uma ServletController que manda para uma classe que executa a lógica.

```
public class AlteraContatoLogic implements Logica {
@Override
public Pagina run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // buscando os parâmetros no request
    long id = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
    String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
    //String endereco = new String(request.getParameter("endereco").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String endereco = request.getParameter("endereco");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String telefone = request.getParameter("telefone");
    String dataEmTexto = request.getParameter("dataNascimento");
    Calendar dataNascimento = null;

    // fazendo a conversão da data
    try {
        Date date = sdf_dmy.parse(dataEmTexto);
        dataNascimento = Calendar.getInstance();
        dataNascimento.setTime(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }

    // monta um objeto contato
    Contato contato = new Contato();
    contato.setNome(nome);
    contato.setEndereco(endereco);
    contato.setEmail(email);
    contato.setDataNascimento(dataNascimento);
    contato.setTelefone(telefone);
    contato.setId(id);

    // altera no bd
    new ContatoDao().set(contato);

    return new Redirecionador(request, response, "./");
}
```

}

Alguém sabe o que pode ser e como solucionar?
Grato desde já.

Comment: Qual a colação da tabela seu banco ? na maioria das vezes basta inserir o metodo nativo utf8_encode() nas váriaves que podem vir a ter acentuação.

Comment: charset=utf8 e collate=utf8_general_ci

Comment: Tenta mudar pra latin, eu uso assim pelo menos, e raramente da algum problema de codificação:
charset = Latin1 e collate = latin1_general_cs . O cs é para diferenciar entre M e m.

Comment: Tanto com cs ou ci como collate, ainda não muda na exibição. Continua estranha.

Comment: Coloca na pergunta uma exemplo de linha que traga o erro e o trecho do código

Comment: Já testou em outro navegador?

Comment: Consegui! Migrei para o postgresql com o banco tendo encoding=utf8, collate=pt_BR.UTF-8 e Ctype=pt_BR.UTF-8 e na charset das páginas usando iso-8859-1.